# WPF: Model to View Model data binding to implement Two Step View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, databinding

I am trying to use [Two Step View](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html) pattern in WPF. The problem is about keeping things in sync – I need a way to data-bind models to view models. Are there any good existing solutions? My approach is to introduce `Property<T>` to be used this way:

```
public abstract class TextField : ObservableObject
{
    public Property<bool> IsEnabled { get; set; } = true;
    public Property<string> Text { get; set; } = false;
    // etc.
}
```

Where property supports databinding updates:

```
public class Property<T> : ObservableObject
{
    public static implicit operator Property<T>(T value) => new Property<T>(() => value);
    public static implicit operator T(Property<T> property) => property.Value;

    public Property(Func<T> getter, params INotifyPropertyChanged[] dataSources)
        : this(getter, v => { throw new NotSupportedException(); }, dataSources)
    {            
    }

    public Property(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, params INotifyPropertyChanged[] dataSources)
    {
        Getter = getter;
        Setter = setter;
        foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
            dataSource.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return Getter(); }
        set { Setter(value); }
    }

    Func<T> Getter { get; }
    Action<T> Setter { get; }
}
```

I use helper method Bind in the following way for view model construction:

```
        var model = new DocumentModel();
        var viewModel = new TextField 
        { 
           Text = model.Bind(m => m.FullName), 
           IsEnabled = model.Bind(m => m.FullName != "") 
        };
```

Where bind defined as:

```
public static class Binding
{
    public static Property<TTarget> Bind<TSource, TTarget>(this TSource source, Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> mapper)
        where TSource : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Mapping<TSource, TTarget> mapping = mapper;
        return new Property<TTarget>(() => mapping[source], v => mapping[source] = v, source);
    }
}
```

Where `Mapping` compiles getter and setter from the expression:

```
class Mapping<TSource, TTarget>
{
    public static implicit operator Mapping<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> mapping) =>
        new Mapping<TSource, TTarget>(mapping);

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public Mapping(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> mapper)
    {
        Field = mapper.Parameters[0].Name;
        Getter = mapper.Compile().Invoke;

        try
        {
            var newValue = Expression.Parameter(mapper.Body.Type);
            var assign = Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TTarget>>(
                Expression.Assign(mapper.Body, newValue),
                mapper.Parameters[0], newValue);

            Setter = assign.Compile().Invoke;
        }
        catch(ArgumentException)
        {
        }
    }

    public string Field { get; }

    public TTarget this[TSource source]
    {
        get { return Getter(source); }
        set { Setter(source, value); }
    }

    Func<TSource, TTarget> Getter { get; }
    Action<TSource, TTarget> Setter { get; }
}
```

It works somehow:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type f:TextField}">
    <TextBox 
        Text="{Binding Path=Text.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabled.Value}"/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

Does it look ugly? Two Step View helps me a lot…

Comment: IMO XAML basically is the first step in the 2 step view. It feels like you now have a 3 step view, which is overly abstracted and over engineered. FWIW.

Comment: Yep, something like this - but we always have it in MVVM (M-V-VM). I just do not see how XAML defines a provable contract, which is an idea behind the pattern. Compiler does not check bindings as far as I know. I am also looking for a way to easily introduce calculable bindings.

Comment: the compiler won't enforce the binding, but it will warn you if it can't resolve. Crank up your compiler warnings so they're errors instead. Just a thought.

Comment: Yep, will do, thanks. BTW, I still think that I need to data-bind VM to M, and the simplest way would probably be to inherit VM from `FrameworkElement` (please see below). Is it supposed to be done this way in WPF? Are there any known side effects of using none CLR properties for VM?

Comment: Oops, got it. Data-binding works with `DependencyObject` using third party class, it is not necessary to inherit huge `FrameworkElement`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I redefined it now. Demo:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dvm = new DemoViewModel();
    var dm = new DemoModel();
    dvm.Text = dm.Select(m => m.Text); // bidirectional
    dvm.Text2 = dm.Select(m => m.Text); // bidirectional
    dvm.IsReadOnly = dm.Select(m => m.Text.Length > 4); // calculable
    DataContext = dvm;
}
```

Where:

```
class DemoModel : Model
{
    string _text = "";

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { Set(() => Text, ref _text, value); }
    }
}
```

And (too verbose, but it is a stupid WPF thing):

```
class DemoViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(DemoViewModel));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty Text2Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text2", typeof(string), typeof(DemoViewModel));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReadOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsReadOnly", typeof(bool), typeof(DemoViewModel));

    public Binding<string> Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetBinding(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public Binding<string> Text2
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(Text2Property); }
        set { SetBinding(Text2Property, value); }
    }

    public Binding<bool> IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReadOnlyProperty); }
        set { SetBinding(IsReadOnlyProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Library classes:

```
class Model : ObservableObject
{
}
```

And:

**Outdated** - see below:

```
class ViewModel : FrameworkElement
{
    protected BindingExpressionBase SetBinding<T>
        (DependencyProperty dp, Binding<T> property)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value") 
            { Source = property, Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };

        return SetBinding(dp, binding);
    }
}
```

**Now**

```
public class ViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    protected BindingExpressionBase SetBinding<T>(DependencyProperty dp, Binding<T> property)
    {
        var binding = new Binding("Value")
        {
            Source = property,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
        };

        return BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, dp, binding);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public static class ModelBinding
{
    public static Binding<T> Select<TM, T>(this TM m, Expression<Func<TM, T>> mapper)
    {
        Mapping<TM, T> mapping = mapper;
        return new Binding<T>(() => mapping[m], v => mapping[m] = v, m);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class Binding<T> : ObservableObject
{
    public static implicit operator Binding<T>(T value) => new Binding<T>(() => value);        
    public static implicit operator T(Binding<T> property) => property.Value;

    public Binding(Func<T> getter, params object[] dataSources)
        : this(getter, v => { throw new NotSupportedException(); }, dataSources)
    {
    }

    public Binding(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, params object[] dataSources)
    {
        Getter = getter;
        Setter = setter;            
        foreach (var npc in dataSources.OfType<INotifyPropertyChanged>())
            npc.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get { return Getter(); }
        set { Setter(value); }
    }

    Func<T> Getter { get; }
    Action<T> Setter { get; }
}
```

And:

```
class Mapping<TSource, TTarget>
{
    public static implicit operator Mapping<TSource, TTarget>(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> mapping) =>
        new Mapping<TSource, TTarget>(mapping);

    [DebuggerHidden]
    public Mapping(Expression<Func<TSource, TTarget>> mapper)
    {
        Getter = mapper.Compile().Invoke;

        try
        {
            var newValue = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(mapper.Body.Type);
            var assign = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda<Action<TSource, TTarget>>(
                System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Assign(mapper.Body, newValue),
                mapper.Parameters[0], newValue);

            Setter = assign.Compile().Invoke;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
        }
    }

    public TTarget this[TSource source]
    {
        get { return Getter(source); }
        set { Setter(source, value); }
    }

    Func<TSource, TTarget> Getter { get; }
    Action<TSource, TTarget> Setter { get; }
}
```